# Show More/Less with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, click

I need a simple read more/less example in pure javascript and CSS. How can I convert this jQuery example to pure Javascript?
 https://jsfiddle.net/ngaffer/s75zj385/2/

I have several long paragraphs being generated on a page. In order to shorten the page to minimize scrolling, I want to hide the majority of each paragraph and display a link "read more". When the link is clicked the button will display the hidden text and change the link to "read less".

```
<section>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <a class="show-more" href="#">Show more</a>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <a class="show-more" href="#">Show more</a>
</section>

<script>
$("a.show-more").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    

    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});
</script>

<style>
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}
.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conversion like this isn't a very lengthy process.

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5svXF2Y7VAhUFeT4KHU0DAfwQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyoumightnotneedjquery.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEb0YDh-L5qff31FLt3d76browF9g) is a very useful resource to know how to replace a common jquery code with plain (vanilla) javascript.

At the same time, I also took the liberty of modifying your javascript in a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq9z8qxL/1/).

```
var click_event = function() {
    var linkText = this.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
        this.innerHTML = "Show less";
        this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("hideContent");
        this.previousElementSibling.classList.add("showContent");

    }
    else {
        this.innerHTML = "Show more";
        this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("showContent");
        this.previousElementSibling.classList.add("hideContent");
    }
};

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', click_event, false);
}
```

This code implements all the basic functionalities in vanilla JS. However, I have left out the 400ms time delay, which I think would be a very interesting exercise for you to work on. I hope this helps you in future events.

Comment: Thank you for the updated fiddle. This works great for me! One quick adjustment to the anchor href to prevent jumping back to top on click, add a forward slash after the hashtag - not sure if this is best practice but it works. https://jsfiddle.net/ngaffer/vq9z8qxL/2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I never realized that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS code that select anchors based on the class and with animation css trick:

```js
var anchrorClassShow=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<anchrorClassShow.length;i++){  
  if(anchrorClassShow[i].className!=='show-more'){    
    anchrorClassShow[i].remove();
  }  
}


 
for(var i=0;i<anchrorClassShow.length;i++){
  anchrorClassShow[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  var parentDiv=this.parentElement;  
  if(parentDiv.children[0].className.match(/hideContent/g)){
     parentDiv.children[0].className='content showContent';
  }else{
     parentDiv.children[0].className='content hideContent';
  }
});
}
```

```css
.hideContent {
    max-height: 2em;
    transition: max-height 0.15s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d5d5d5;
    
}
.showContent {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.35s linear; 
    
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <a class="show-more" href="#">Show more</a>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <a class="show-more" href="#">Show more</a>
</section>
```